# is there a way to make "project clean", and start tomcat through cmd?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I wanna know if there is a way to make this process through cmd to make a .bat and start my app with only one click (now i need 4 cliks, is not a big deal).

in eclipse:

Project clean.. (+build) -> (tomcat) clean... -> clean tomcat work directory -> start tomcat

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Using the command line

If you want to run everything from the command line, I think that the easiest would be to configure your project so that it can be built with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org). I have never used Tomcat so I can't really help here but there's a lot of documentation online. See for instance [this post](http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-run-embedded-tomcat-with-maven/) for an explanation on how to run Tomcat as part of a Maven build.

You could thus run you application with the following command:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

### Using Eclipse IDE

If you just want to spare yourself a few clicks within Eclipse I think that you could give [Eclipse EASE](https://www.eclipse.org/ease/) a try. Basically, it's a plug-in that allows you to execute Python scripts within Eclipse IDE. I have never used it but it looks like can use it to customize the IDE so you might be able to create a button that does the four steps you mentioned. See the following blog post: [How to use Python to hack your IDE](https://opensource.com/life/16/2/how-use-python-hack-your-ide).

I am not sure that I really answered your question but since I cannot comment yet I tried to anyway. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look!